# Hide columns if user want that

Tags: php, mysql

This probably has a super simpel solutions, but i can't wrap my head around it.

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT traning.type_name,users.user_id,
      users.user_name,user_traning.min_puls,
      user_traning.medel_puls,user_traning.max_puls,
      user_traning.duration,user_traning.date, user_traning.view
      from traning inner join user_traning 
      on traning.tr_id=user_traning.tr_id
      inner join users on user_traning.user_id=users.user_id 
      ORDER BY `user_traning`.`date` DESC
```

I have a colum in user_traning that is called `view`.

The input form inputs either `null` or a `2`. Im thinking that NULL means that everyone could view the input, and a 2 is that the user want to hide the input.

I have been trying to it this way:

```
while($row = $users_traning->fetchObject())
     {
        if($row->user_id == $_SESSION['user_id'] && $row->view == NULL)
        {
echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <a href="userinfo.php='.$row->user_id.'">You </a> have ' .$row->type_name. ' for ' .round($minuter,2). ' min';
echo '<br>';
        }else{        
echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> <a href="userinfo.php='.$row->user_id.'">'.$row->user_name.' </a> has been ' .$row->type_name. ' i ' .round($minuter,2). ' for';
    echo '<br>';
}}
```

As you can see; if the user has selected to hide their input (inserted a 2) the row is displayed with a glyphicon-user, if not, it is displayed with glyphicon-globe.

I want to output everything, except the rows from other users that have inserted a `2` in column view. But my "own" rows is still displayed with the corresponding glyphicons.

How can i do this?

Help much appreciated!

Comment: what you mean by 'But my "own" rows is still displayed with the corresponding glyphicons.' .... Are you getting both the glyphicons ..?

Comment: I want to be able to see my own rows where i have selected to hide the row, where i have inserted a `2` in column view. And that row should be displayed with `glyphicon-user`. But i don't want to se other users rows, where they have selected to hide their row. My "public" rows, with `NULL` in view, should be display for everyone with  `glyphicon-globe. Hope it made sense =)

Comment: you wanted to show `view 2` to the logged in user... but you still get the glyphicon-globe..

Comment: Example: Two users, user1 and user2. User1 makes two entries. One public and one non-public. User2 makes four entries, two public and two non-public. User1´s dash will show four entries, his two entries and two entris from user2. User1 will see one of his entries with `glyphicon-globe` (this tells user1 that this is public) and another entrie with `glyphicon-user` (this tells user1 that this is only viewible by user1). user2 will see 5 entries, three (one from user1) with `glyphicon-globe` and and two with `glyphicon-user` (from user2). =)

Comment: i have given a answer let me know if i'm wrong anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let assume that user1 has been logged in..

```
while($row = $users_traning->fetchObject())
{
    if($row->user_id == $_SESSION['user_id']){ //For user1 

        $glyphicon = (empty($row->view)) ? 'user' : 'globe' ; // if $row->view is null 'user' is assigned else 'globe'

        echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-'.$glyphicon.'"></span> <a href="userinfo.php='.$row->user_id.'">You </a> have ' .$row->type_name. ' for ' .round($minuter,2). ' min';
                echo '<br>';


    }elseif($row->user_id != $_SESSION['user_id'] && empty($row->view)){ // For user2

        echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> <a href="userinfo.php='.$row->user_id.'">'.$row->user_name.' </a> has been ' .$row->type_name. ' i ' .round($minuter,2). ' for';
                echo '<br>';

    }
}
```